# UnitTest - Test upload file

Tags: php, unit-testing

I working with PHPUnit and have a problem.

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fl']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['fl']['error'] === 0)
{
    ...
}
```

My test file:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $_FILES = array(
        'fl' => array(
            'name' => 'test.jpg',
            'type' => 'image/jpeg',
            'size' => 1024,
            'tmp_name' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../files/images/img.jpg',
            'error' => 0
        )
    );
}
```

`is_uploaded_file()` always return `false` because no file is uploaded, so I couldn't test this block code. What I would like to do is test it if `is_uploaded_file()` is `true`.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't directly access superglobals like FILES/GET/POST/SERVER etc in your code. It's hard to test. When you use some wrapper, it's easy to mock.

Comment: Hi @dragoste, i should use mock to control result of is_uploaded_file? :)

Comment: `is_uploaded_file` is PHPs function. I'm pretty sure you don't have to test the function itself. ;-) So the question is what *unit* you're testing.

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you very much :).